# How to apply opeartions in Mongoose's where() method

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

[image]

as you can see from the picture I have big earthquake data in the database, which I'm trying to get last year's earthquakes. but properties.time is a string so I can't actually compare. I know how to convert ISO string to miliseconds but how can I do it while I'm querying the database? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.find(query)
.where('properties.time')
.gt(new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 1, 0, 1))
```

Comment: are you sure you read the question

Comment: Could you share the format hold in db ?